# Naive Bayes model - Missing output variable for specific sample(s)

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes-classifier, missing-data

With Naive Bayes model can we discard a training sample if the value of the sample's output variable is missing?

And would that not make any difference to the parameter learning of the Naive Bayes model?